# Как лучше реализовать структуру БД

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

На сайте будет много разделов:

- новости;
- объявления;
- публикации;
- партнёры;
- научные работы;
- ... и другие пункты.

Нужно реализовать так, чтобы всё было на 3-х языках, можно было переключить, и все пункты будут на английском и т.д.

Как лучше реализовать? Для каждой категории создавать 3 таблицы:

> [НовостиРУС,новостиУКР,новостиАНГ]

и так для всех пунктов, каждая под определенный язык, или 1 таблица, но в 3 раза больше столбцов?

Если таблиц будет больше, по идее, сайт будет лучше работать, т.к. если установлен 1 язык, то будет всегда использовать по 1-й таблице заданной категории, а иначе по 1-й, но которая в 3 раза тяжелея.

Каково ваше мнение? Как по мне, так лучше уж пусть 60-90 таблиц будет, зато быстродействие и нагрузка меньше.

Comment: >Если таблиц будет больше, по идее сайт будет лучше работать, т.к, если установлен 1 язык, то будет всегда использовать по 1-й таблце изданной категории, а иначе по 1-й но которая в 3 раза тяжелея.

а вы вообще уверены, что достаточно хорошо понимаете принцип организации и внутренней работы вашей СУБД, чтобы делать такие далекоидущие выводы?

Comment: Ну для этого я и решил спросить совета у вас.

Comment: > Каково ваше мнение? как по мне, так лучше уж пусть 60-90 таблиц будет, зато быстродействие и нагрузка меньше.

Разработчик стоит 30k-120k-XXXk в месяц.  
Хостинг стоит < 1k в месяцю

Comment: @Юра Сучко http://habrahabr.ru/post/194714/ на тебе ссылку на простейший ужатый туториал по твоей теме. Немного теории тебе не помешает. Ссылка на последнюю часть. остальные в шапке страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Таблица Язык
id   название
1    РУС
2    УКР
3    АНГ

Таблица Новости
id   язык_id   текст
1    2         новость на украинском
2    3         новость на английском
3    1         новость на русском
```

Comment: Не очень хорошее решение, лучше создавать отдельные таблицы с префиксом языка. Так все действия(выборка/добавление/редактирование) будут намного быстрее. 
При малых объемах это будет не заметно и подойдет метод @kosost, а вот если у Вас крупный проект - то бери мой вариант.

П.С. Лучше сразу привыкать к хорошим вещам :)

Comment: Вам привести пример, когда такой подход работать не будет? (Если правда интересно, то только вечером смогу.)

Т.е. будет, до некоторого момента времени, а потом на определенной новости споткнется. И что вы будете делать? Править новости или переписывать всю архитектуру?

@Юра Сучко, а чем вас gettext не устраивает?

Comment: @BOPOH, конечно, приведите пример, по которому мой метод работать не будет. Жду с нетерпением. :)

Comment: @МаринаВоин, мой комментарий относился к ответу тов. @kosost. Ваш метод просто не нравится тем, что локализация в базе. Если есть уже готовое, то почему бы не использовать это? Одно дело, когда что-то не устраивает и вы своим способом хотите это исправить, другое дело, когда только учишься и пишешь велосипед.

Comment: Если речь идет об объемах facebook то, конечно, можно забить на нормализацию и на многое другое в угоду производительности, но если нет, то, @МаринаВоин, ваш метод принесет много проблем, например, при добавлении еще одного языка.

Comment: Данный метод немного сложнее в реализации, чем Ваш. Но он куда удобнее, а в плане расширения просто сказка. Тут все зависит от того, смотрите ли Вы в будущее или просто хотите сделать абы как, чтобы работало.

Comment: > а в плане расширения просто сказка

серьезно?

Comment: Ладно, вижу тут одни тролли и с серьезными (крупными) проектами не работали. Спорить с Вами и доказывать что-либо не вижу смысла, используете и далее свои методы.

Comment: Упс... Немного не так понял ответ. Мне че-то показалось, что новости на разных языках в одной строке хранятся, тогда была бы ошибка. А в текущем варианте - опять велосипед, когда есть готовые средства.

Comment: [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) - не скажу, что его активно используем (т.к. сами любители велосипедов), но там где использовали, проблем не знали.

И в текущем виде если использовать - а что если надо не только текст, но и кучу другой инфы хранить? Например, цена/количество/качество и т.д.? Дублировать информацию в каждой локализации?

А если для данной записи будет отсутствовать локализация? Еще одно обращение к базе? А если вы выбираете 500 записей? Для каждой будете проверять и запрашивать? А если заголовок есть, а текста нет? С gettext`ом такой проблемы нет.

Comment: ой, все так негативно реагируют...google translate вам в помощь, и не надо мультиязычноть разрабатывать :)

Comment: @BOPOH

век живи, век учись. Оказывается есть штатный способ, а подобное ручками реализовал у себя. Это получается всего лишь удобное дополнение к структуре описанной выше. Во всяком случае, у меня работает именно так: таблицы хранят основную информацию, систематизированную, а всякие сообщения, заголовки и прочая лабуда общего характера лежит отдельно и доступна по ключу. То есть на сайте в любом месте ставлю ключ, а он заменяется на текст в текущей локали.